# Can a single spring data source take multiple urls?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-rds, spring-jdbc

Regarding the potential failover of an AWS RDS db from east region -> west region, I need to be able to failover graciously. It's simpler if it were the same region multi-AZ since only one DNS needs to be maintained, but I can't think of a good solution in this case.

Can a spring datasource take multiple URL's?

Example:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://url1.com/db1, jdbc:postgresql://url2.com/db1
```

I have not seen any information really on whether or not this is possible, local testing seems to say that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the kind of thing I would ordinarily rely upon Spring for.

Amazon-rds should have some kind of failover feature. And, depending on how your SpringBoot is deployed, you should be able to set it up to die gracefully during any interruption.

Lacking explicit features in Amazon-rds, you should also be able to set up a load balancer in AWS that will give you continuity of address, if not continuity of connection.

Comment: Postgresql driver defines a failover of a comma delimited list of url's to databases. I realize mine is malformed in my post, but it's still not working even when formatted correctly. https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-fail-over